# An error occurred: SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5) when running Symfony security checker

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am attempting to running the Symfony Security Checker locally however I am experiencing an issue relating to the SSL connection.

I have tried trashing the `SSL_CERT_FILE` env variable with:

`unset SSL_CERT_FILE`

...but that had no effect after logging out and back in to my session.

I've looked at my `~/.bash_profile` but can't see anything in here:

```
alias ll='ls -lG'
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"

if [ -f `brew --prefix`/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
fi
```

...or in my `~/.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    name = Picco
    email = crmpicco@ayrshireminis.com
```

The error I get is:

> An error occurred: SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5).

`openssl s_client -host security.sensiolabs.org -port 443`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
5357:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.6/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:
```

`openssl s_client -host security.sensiolabs.org -port 443 -cipher 'DEFAULT:!ECDH'`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
3172:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64.50.6/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:
```

`curl -sik -H "Accept: application/json" -F "lock=@composer.lock" https://security.sensiolabs.org/check_lock`

Returns no error or output at all.

Comment: What's the md5 of your `vendor/sensiolabs/security-checker/SensioLabs/Security/Resources/security.sensiolabs.org.crt` ?

Comment: Also, what's the output of `openssl s_client -host security.sensiolabs.org -port 443` ?

Comment: You could use their online site ([Link](https://security.sensiolabs.org/check)) aswell, just upload your `composer.lock` there. It's the same thing the `security:check` command does.

Comment: @ccKep Thanks for your comments. I have updated my question. I am aware of the online upload, but it's not as useful as just running a script locally and getting some parse-able output.

Comment: Which openssl version are you using (presumably `0.9.8`)? Try seeing if the problem occurs in other versions aswell, working fine on `1.0.2g` for me.

Comment: @ccKep I am on `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`. What is the output when you run that command on 1.0.2?

Comment: Pastebin of output: [Link](https://pastebin.com/xvrn7FU9). What does `openssl s_client -host security.sensiolabs.org -port 443 -cipher 'DEFAULT:!ECDH'` print?

Comment: @ccKep I have updated my question with the output from the latest `openssl` call. I think you are onto something with the version of OpenSSL. I can connect to the security checker on another box running OpenSSL 1.0.2h. I'm just nervous about upgrading as i've seen a few posts on SO where people have had problems upgrading on Mac OS. I'm on Sierra and haven't found a solid upgrade guide for it yet...

Comment: If you really don't want to start fiddling with your openssl version you could write yourself a small bash script that just runs curl and POSTs the composer.lock to security.sensiolabs.org and use the `-k` flag (*Allow connections to SSL sites without cert*): `curl -sik -H "Accept: application/json" -F "lock=@composer.lock" https://security.sensiolabs.org/check_lock`

Comment: Or you could go the long route and replace the `sensio_distribution.security_checker` service with an instance of your own that uses a copy of the `CurlCrawler` that ignores the SSL verification.

Comment: @ccKep Thanks for the suggestion, but that has no effect on the call to the security checker. I still get the "An error occurred: SSL: certiificate verification failed" message. Does that `cURL` make any permanent changes?

Comment: No, it's a replacement command since the `security:checker` command alsways verifies certs. It POSTs your `composer.lock` to `https://security.sensiolabs.org/check_lock`, the result you get are any alerts (in json format) and some headers (most notable `X-Alerts:` specifying the number of warnings)

Comment: try Local PHP Security Checker instead